# Program group item with custom command line for different Launchers

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to install an exe program and associated files. This is a cross platform C# program that can be run with Mono on Linux/Mac or just run as is on Windows. I am not finding any examples on creating a desktop icon and program group icon for this. On windows I just want to have the exe inside of the installed files with an icon I choose. On Linux/Mac I want to have a command run "mono myprogram.exe"

Answer (score 0):

In the launchers section, you can add external launchers. The "Create program group" action will treat them like the generated launchers.

> On Linux/Mac I want to have a command run "mono myprogram.exe"

You should put that command into a shell script and use that shell script as an external launcher.